# Use execute immediate in procedure for DML and passing character value in parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a delete procedure which is taking table name and some values to delete record from that table, hence I have created a procedure with execute immediate which is forming the delete query by taking the parameter and delete.

But when ever I am passing the char value in the parameter it is getting error :

```
invalid identifier
```

as query formed with out single quote for the character value. Please let me know how can I pass char value in the procedure to form a string correctly.

Below is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Prd_delete(p_tbl_name IN VARCHAR2,
                                       p_sys      VARCHAR2,
                                       p_b_id     VARCHAR2,
                                       p_c_date   NUMBER)
IS
  dlt_query VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    dlt_query := 'delete from '
                 ||p_tbl_name
                 ||' where system='
                 ||p_sys
                 || ' And batch_id='
                 ||p_b_id
                 || ' And cobdate='
                 ||p_c_date;

    --dbms_output.put_line(dlt_query);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dlt_query;
END;

/
```

Below is the running command :

```
exec prd_delete ('TBL_HIST_DATA','M','N1',20141205);
```

Below is the error :

```
ORA-00904:"N1" invalid identifier.
```

How to pass this value correctly ? please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- At first place, why do you need `PL/SQL` for the `DELETE`. You could do it in plain `SQL`.
- Why is `P_C_DATE` a `NUMBER`, What data type is `cobdate` COLUMN. A date should always be a `DATE`. If the column data type is `DATE`, then you will run into more errors. Always pay attention to declaring correct data types.

With `dynamic SQL`, before directly executing, it is always a good practice to see whether the query is formed correctly using `DBMS_OUTPUT`. I would also suggest to use `quoting string literal technique` to make it even easier.

`DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(dlt_query);`

The issue with the query is that you are missing the `single-quotation` marks around the `VARCHAR2` type.

Modify the query to -

```
dlt_query := 'delete from '||P_TBL_NAME||' where system='||P_SYS||
             ' And batch_id='||''''||P_B_ID|| '''' ||
             ' And cobdate='||P_C_DATE;
```

Comment: As we need to pass table name from a unix shell to oracle DB i required to to it like this.. and cobdate is a number datatype as for the design . I cant change it to DATE datatype. anyway thanks for the Ans.@lalit

Comment: @sabyasachikar, if it fixed your issue, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

you are losing the quotes around N1 during concatination

you can fix by adding quotes before and after , eg.

```
dlt_query := 'delete from '||P_TBL_NAME||' where system='||P_SYS||
' And batch_id='||''''||P_B_ID|| '''' ||
' And cobdate='||P_C_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement, you should use bind variables:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prd_delete (P_TBL_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                                P_SYS VARCHAR2,
                                                P_B_ID VARCHAR2,
                                                P_C_DATE NUMBER) IS
          dlt_query   VARCHAR2 (200);
    BEGIN
      dlt_query := 'delete from ' || P_TBL_NAME || ' where system=:1 and batch_id=:2 and cobdate=:3';
      BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dlt_query USING P_SYS, P_B_ID, P_C_DATE;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          -- catch exception !!
      END;
    END;
   /
```